# How to present UIView from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

In my app I have a `UITableViewCell` with a button in it.

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.y+5, self.frame.origin.x+53, 200, 200)];
    test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    test.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    test.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self addSubview:test];
}
```

However, this red view is presented behind the section headers. What's the best way to add it to the view from inside the `UITableViewCell` in a proper way?

Comment: use viewForHeaderInSection method of UItableView.

Answer (score 0):

Get the cell you want to add it to, and then use

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: test];
```

You can get the cell from the button's frame.origin by converting the point to the table view's coordinate system and using the UITableView method `indexPathForRowAtPoint`. That code might looks like this:

```
- (NSIndexPath *) indexPathForView: (UIView*) view;
{
  CGPoint viewCenter = CGPointMake(
                                       CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds),
                                       CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds)
                                       );
  viewCenter = [self.tableView convertPoint: viewCenter fromView: view];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: viewCenter];
  return indexPath;
}
```

Or better yet, as an extension on UITableView:

```
@implementation UITableView (indexPathForCellContainingView)

- (NSIndexPath *) indexPathForCellContainingView: (UIView *) view;
{
  //get the view's center point (which will be in it's parent view's coordinate system
  //And convert it to the table view's coorindate system
  CGPoint viewCenter = [self convertPoint: view.center fromView: view.superview];

  //Ask the table view which cell's index path contains that point.
  return [self indexPathForRowAtPoint: viewCenter];
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 53, 200, 200)];
    test.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    test.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0f;
    test.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:test];
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explained *why* your suggestion will help.

Comment: In your code 
UIView *test = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.y+5, self.frame.origin.x+53, 200, 200)]; means if cell is in the (0,0) coordinate of its super view then test view will have a coordinate (5,53). But if cell coordinate is (0,50) then test will have a coordinate (55, 53).

Comment: a views coordinate is calculated relative to its super view.